# Resize partitions with gparted

Tags: partition, gparted

Hey I'm trying to resize my boot partition and eventually my LVM partition.

I currently have:

```
/dev/sda1 ext2         243M  
/dev/sda2 extended     7.76G  
unallocated            17G
```

Ideally I'd like:

```
/dev/sda1 ext2         7.2G  
/dev/sda2 extended     17.76G
```

My main problem is my `/` that is too small and I can't install anything anymore.

I tried to resize `/dev/sda1` but the max size is the current one. As I understand it, I need to move the `unallocated space` next to `/dev/sda1` but Gparted doesn't let me. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: So what's stopping you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Keep only `/boot` in the first partition

First, 243MB is enough for `/boot`. If it's the root partition that you have on `/dev/sda1`, then there isn't enough room even for a basic installation. If you've separated `/usr`, don't: this was useful in the days of read-only or shared `/usr` but isn't nowadays.

To move the root partition:

1. Move all the files to the existing partition on the logical volume.
2. Move `/boot` back to `/dev/sda1`.
3. Update your bootloader configuration. For example, if your bootloader is Grub, run `update-grub`. Also update your initrd or initramfs if you have one. The details depend on your distribution.

### How to enlarge the first partition

Given that you have plenty of free space, the easiest solution is to make use of it and move your existing data there.

1. Create a new logical partition `sda6` in the free space with GParted.
2. Create a physical volume in the new partition and add it to the existing volume group. I'll call the volume group `mygroup`.

   ```
   pvcreate /dev/sda6
   vgextend mygroup /dev/sda6
   ```
3. Move the existing logical volume(s) to the new physical volume.

   ```
   pvmove /dev/sda5
   ```
4. Decommission the now-unused physical volume.

   ```
   vgreduce mygroup /dev/sda5
   pvremove /dev/sda5
   ```
5. In GParted, resize and move `/dev/sda5` to make room for a larger `/dev/sda1`, and enlarge `/dev/sda1`.
6. Create a physical volume on `/dev/sda5` and add it to the volume group.

   ```
   pvcreate /dev/sda5
   vgextend mygroup /dev/sda5
   ```

   Use the free space on the volume group as you see fit.
7. Extend the filesystem on `/dev/sda1`.

   ```
   resize2fs /dev/sda1
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can review the [Resize Partitions with gParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=moving-space-between-partitions) but long story short you will need to split this into 2 steps:

1. Move `/dev/sda2`
2. Resize `/dev/sda1`